# Spannable text in a TextView breaks line randomly after the substring "K/" when at least one of both characters has a Span defined on it

Tags: java, android, html, textview

I've discovered a puzzling bug that, from what I can tell, only happens when a `TextView` has a `Spannable` text that contains the substring `K/` and one or both of these characters have a `ForegroundColorSpan` (or maybe spans in general?) set on them (but are *not* in the same span). The effect is that all text following the `/` is forced on a new line, although I've noticed that other symbols like another `/` or a `.` directly following the `K/` stay on the same line.
Additional Note: Both K and X behave the same here, regardless of capitalization.

Needless to say, I have no clue what is going on. My best guess would be some kind of weird formatting interpretation.

What my TextView/MaterialButton should look like:

[image]

What it looks like on my phone:

[image]

It is **not** an issue with the defined width of the TextView, which is set to `wrap_content`. It works fine on all other devices I've tried, even with far longer Strings. It also happens on a completely default TextView with both dimensions set to `wrap_content`.

Some code that recreates the issue on my phone:

```
// Create String which includes "K/"
String textString = "1K/2K";

// Create SpannableString and set a color span up to the first "K"
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(textString);
spannableString.setSpan(
                    new ForegroundColorSpan(someColor),
                    0,
                    textString.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
myMaterialButton.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

This happens 100% of the time on my Samsung J4 Plus with Android 9 (API 28). I've tried to reproduce it on a Pixel 5 Emulator with several Android versions including 9, with the exact same data and situation but there it all works as expected.

If anyone has any kind of insight, tip or any kind of information why this might be happening, I'd be eternally grateful.

*Update*: Inserting ⁠word joiners (⁠⁠⁠\u2060) at both sides of the "/" solved the issue. I guess it might have something to do with the [Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-45.html) that TextView uses.